# Laravel + nginX + Windows 10 + api routing issue (404 Error)

Tags: laravel, nginx, windows-10

I am trying to make a very simple API request with above settings. It is working perfectly if I serve it with artisan serve command. But If I make the request with nginx, it gives 404 error. Thats why I guess the issue is with the nginX. my nginX conf is as follows.

```
server {
    listen 80 ;
    listen [::]:80 ;


    root D:/sites/demo/public;
    index index.php index.html index.htm ;

    server_name laravel.local;

    location / {

            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri /index.php = 404;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: assuming you have fastcgi running on port 9123? what happens if you try to go directly to http://127.0.0.1:9123/index.php?

Comment: If I try on the broser, it says "This site can’t be reached" ..But when I check phpinfo(), I see the FastCGI is enabled..

Comment: does it show which port it is running on? How did you come up with port 9123?

Comment: I set the D:\nginx\RunHiddenConsole.exe D:\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9123

BTW, Thank you for your help, but I installed apache and its working now.